# do you have access to contents of iframe loading external website?

Tags: php, javascript, iframe, curl

If I have an iframe loading a website from a different server, like bing.com, can I manipulate or retrieve the code from that iframe?

If not, I can do a curl request and create the iframe from that and then manipulate it, right?

Comment: It would require you to curl the request in some way, but if you did that - why would you put it back into an iframe? But yes - you could manipulate it that way.

Comment: that breaks bing's TOS, and probably a lot of other sites to.

Comment: Dagon, bing.com was an example.

Comment: Regardless of whether or not it was an example, what you are asking is effectively, "how do I setup a fishing site". I like to give people the benefit of the doubt, but I promise you 90% of the people who read your question will assume otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript you can't access the contents of an iframe if that site resides on a different domain than the one you are loading the iframe from. You can proxy the page load by having a PHP scrip that "curls" the request. There is a lot more involved than that though to cleanly proxy another site.